# Jquery $(window).load() not working on Chrome, Opera and Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, window, onload

I would like to explain my situation.

I am writing a website and one of the webpage is using the google map.

The web site is a `cms` website and it is using `ektron`

So, I have to use `ektron google map` coz it provides some features that the customers want.

`Ektron` is simply using `google map` and use ajax to combine with its own logic.

I dun know the details but whenever I tried to change the properties of that `ektron map`, I need to click `search` or `zoom in` or `zoom out` or move the map.

Only after I do that, the properties changed are effected. If not, they don't.

So, I think of the shortcut and programatically cick the `search` button of `ektron map`.

Then again, I am adding the control programatically to a `panel`.

I can't write `document.ready` coz I found out that works before the map is loaded.

So, I wrote this code to make the map works.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function () {
        $("#__GetAddr").click();
    });
</script>
```

It works. `__GetAddr` is the search button ID and I click it after everything loads.

But the problem started when I use it with chrome.

I found out that `$(window).load()` is not working in chrome, safari and opera.

I googled it for a while but can't find any solid answer.

Is there any clear alternative way for that to work in those 3 browsers while it still works for IE7,8,9 and Firefox.

Thanks a lot.

Hi all, I have a solution.

I dun think it's the best solution. but it works.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
        $(window).load(function () { $("#__GetAddr").click(); });
    }
    else {
        window.addEventListener('load', function () { $("#__GetAddr").click();                  }, false);
    }
</script>
```

I would appreciate to have a better one. :P

Comment: Are you getting any JavaScript errors? Check the console for your browser and see if any errors are being thrown during the page load.

Comment: I don't think this is the right approach. On the surface, you might think "it works when I click, so I just need to simulate that click." The better approach is to find out what function needs to be called to set the properties, and make the proper function call rather than simulating click.

Comment: @LachlanMcDonald There is no error. Just not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
        $(window).load(function () { $("#__GetAddr").click(); });
    } else {
        window.addEventListener('load', function () { $("#__GetAddr").click();                  }, false);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Not working for me. Nor window.addEventListener, nor the jquery version works for me. These are the times, while I really begint to hate chrome more, then Internet Explorer. In my test code I places the two types of load event attachers with console.log messages and nether them got executed. :(

Answer (score 0):

Did you even try document ready for it?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#__GetAddr").click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not nice, but you could use a timeout if you detect that the browser is not Chrome. However I would really try to get some notification from the map itself, once it is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You're using jQuery version 3.1.0 and the load event is deprecated for use since jQuery version 1.8. The load event is removed from jQuery 3.0. Instead, you can use on method and bind the JavaScript load event:

```
$(window).on('load', function () {
      $("#__GetAddr").click();
 });
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try what Google recommends in their Maps API documentation -- putting an onload event in the body tag. This should work for every browser:

```
<body onload="ready()">
```

Then, declare the ready() function below in a script tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ready() {
  $("#__GetAddr").click();
}
</script>
```

Comment: I believe the same can also be accomplished with jQuery's `$(document).ready(function(){ ... })`

Comment: Yea, but that works before the map is loaded. So, that's not working.